# Express Post method can't read property 'toString'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have an express server with the following Post call:

```
app.post('/api/guitars/' , function(req, res){
    const body = req.body;
    //var inputGuitar = new Guitar(body.guitarMake.toString(), body.guitarModel.toString(), body.guitarSerial.toString(), body.guitarColour.toString(), body.guitarOwnerId.toString(), body.guitarYear.toString());
    db.query(`INSERT INTO Guitar (GuitarMake, GuitarModel, GuitarSerial, GuitarColour, GuitarOwnerId, GuitarYear) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
    [body.guitarMake.toString(), body.inputGuitar.guitarModel.toString(), body.guitarSerial.toString(), body.guitarColour.toString(), body.guitarOwnerId.toString(), body.guitarYear.toString()], function(err, res){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(res);
        }
    }); 

    res.end();
});
```

My front end code which is a React.js app is console logging this JSON object:

```
{"guitarMake":"Fender",
"guitarModel":"Jazzmaster",
"guitarSerial":"000000001",
"guitarColour":"Placid Blue",
"guitarOwnerId":"dummyuser",
"guitarYear":"2019"}
```

Which gets generated at this block:

```
if (isValid) {
            var guitar = {
                "guitarMake" : this.state.GuitarMake,
                "guitarModel" : this.state.GuitarModel,
                "guitarSerial" : this.state.GuitarSerial,
                "guitarColour" : this.state.GuitarColour,
                "guitarOwnerId" : this.state.GuitarOwnerId,
                "guitarYear" : this.state.GuitarYear
            }
            var json = JSON.stringify(guitar);
            console.log(json);
            // do something..
            fetch("APIGATEWAY", {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body: json,
            }).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            });
```

Everytime I send the request to the server I am getting an error saying: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined. When I console log the request on the backend express server it looks like this:

```
{ '{"guitarMake":"Fender","guitarModel":"Jazzmaster","guitarSerial":"000000001","guitarColour":"Placid Blue","guitarOwnerId":"dummyuser","guitarYear":"2019"}': '' }
```

I can't figure out why my request looks like this. It's only when it get sent through react app. On postman it looks normal on the server end. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting the body as a string, not a json.

First, make sure you have added the json middleware to your server object:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Second, you're using the wrong mime-type. If you intend the server to parse a json object, you should use `application/json`:

```
fetch("APIGATEWAY", {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Here!
    },
    body: json,
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```